# Limit number keys which can be selected an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an interface (shown below). Currently all properties are required in it. How can I make it so that only one property is required. Basically the properties are mutually exclusive so for example ff a 'top' property is selected then no other property can be selected.

```
interface PaddingOptions {
    'top': number;
    'bottom': number;
    'left': number;
    'right': number;
}
```

```
const foo: PaddingOptions = {top: 20, bottom: 20} //this should give error as both top and bottom can not be used
const foo: PaddingOptions = {right: 20}; // ok as only one property is selected
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, may be it's me, but @Zain Zafar's answer does not fit, since `XOR<,>` like he defined is constrained to only two type arguments.
Extending that `XOR<,>` type to more type arguments would be quite verbose and not even flexible.

Following the same [article](https://timhwang21.gitbook.io/index/programming/typescript/xor-type) where the `XOR<,>` type came, though, there was an alternative which looks a bit more flexible, the `OneOf<,>`.
`OneOf<,>` defines the same solution as `XOR<,>` but expecting only one type definition with no recursive typing (like `XOR<,>` needs).
To fit the problem by using `XOR<,>` we would need something like so

```
type PaddingOptions = XOR<{right: number}, 
                          XOR<{left: number}, 
                              XOR<{bottom: number}, {top: number}>>>;
```

Which becomes really unpleasant to read.

`OneOf<,>` becomes quite trickier to read, but easy to implement

```
type OneOf<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    [Key in K]: Pick<Required<T>, Key> & { 
        [InnerKey in Exclude<K, Key>]?: never; 
    };
}[K];
```

Well, I just wiped out the `Omit<T, K> & ...` which in our case will result to `never & ...` (*redundant*), because we are passing all keys from `T`.

So, implemeting `OneOf<,>` for the question case is as easy as

```
type PaddingOptionKeys = 'top' | 'right' | 'bottom' | 'left';
type PaddingOptions = OneOf<{ [Key in PaddingOptionKeys]: number; }, PaddingOptionKeys>;

const option: PaddingOptions = { left: 9 }; // OK
const option2: PaddingOptions = { right: 9 }; // Still OK
const option3: PaddingOptions = { right: 9, left: 0 }; // Throws error
```

Hence, by using `OneOf<,>` we constraint multiple keys in a comfortably way, easy to read and flexible.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
// XOR implementation
type Without<T, U> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]?: never };
type XOR<T, U> = (T | U) extends object ? (Without<T, U> & U) | (Without<U, T> & T) : T | U;

// Usage
type PaddingOptions = XOR<{ top: number } , { bottom: number }, { right: number }, { left: number }>

const foo: PaddingOptions = {top: 20, bottom: 20} // Will throw error
const bar: PaddingOptions = {bottom: 20}; // Won't throw error
```

this should do the trick.

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-AHQ53u71U-XNGkjkXy9GldQ1drHO5h6Qx8NoGC08E8HcAWg8GYW053gF0jRUHAGg8MgvEQeABgYEFwywFBGHLdgGGYSB+DFdREgQ+A9EFUAACIRQYRAan0YikhxYjwAcVAAHJhAAOUgCRiKCFQzW+MhdkELCtEgY5UEcBRXGkPBQCcWCdFGZCBPRRAYWEK5vkkODohEAwOBxboWDYLhuCCEogA)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I can not add additional dependencies to my project.

Comment: I have removed the additional dependency hope it works for you now.